# aspect orientated programming frameworks

Tags: c#, .net, postsharp

What are the advantages of using aspect orientated programming frameworks like [postsharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) over doing it manually? Thanks.

Comment: It saves time and enforces proper design. But i bet you already read that on the link you posted.

Comment: Yes indeed. However, I have to justify frameworks rather than doing it manually, which you can. My main argument is productivity. I just wanted to check whether there is anything else that I have overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a deep dive you can read Matthew D. Groves [AOP in .NET: Pracitical Aspect-Oriented Programming](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9781617291142?iid=2013-07-blog-aop-book-9781617291142-SBOBlog).

Otherwise, the head guy at [postsharp](/questions/tagged/postsharp), [Gael Fraiteur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74435/gael-fraiteur), is on SO from time to time, so he might also pop in here.

At it's core AOP is about seperating out 'cross cutting concerns' from your main logic.  Things like logging, transaction management, etc are used throughout an application, but the code is not specific to a given class and is used repetitiously. AOP allows you to brake this code out of your classes and stick them elsewhere.

From https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2013/07/17/why-you-should-be-using-aspect-oriented-programming/:

```
using System.Linq;

public class StringReverser
{
    IMyLogger _log;

    public StringReverser(IMyLogger logger)
    {
       _log = logger;
    }

     public string Reverse(string text)
     {
        _log.WriteLine("MyFunction: " + DateTime.Now);
        _log.WriteLine("text (string) argument: " + text);

        string result = null;
        if (text != null)
            result = new string(text.Reverse().ToArray());

        _log.WriteLine("Return value: " + result);

       return result;
   }
```

}

The logging code has nothing to do with `Reverse` and clutters up the code that actually gets work done.  AOP allows you to move that code to a separate place:

```
  public class StringReverser : IStringReverser
  {
      [LoggingAspect]
      public string Reverse(string text)
      {
        if (text == null)
           return null;
        return new string(text.Reverse().ToArray());
     }
  }
```

And the logging code:

```
  [Serializable]
  public class LoggingAspect : MethodInterceptionAspect
  {
    IMyLogger _log;

    public override void RuntimeInitialize(MethodBase method)
    {
        _log = MyServiceLocator.Get();
    }

    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        var methodName = args.Method.Name;
        var parameters = args.Method.GetParameters();

        _log.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} timestamp: {1}", methodName, 
                DateTime.Now));

        for (var i = 0; i &lt; args.Arguments.Count; i++)
            _log.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} argument #{1}, {2} ({3}): {4}",
                methodName,
                i,
                parameters[i].Name,
                parameters[i].ParameterType,
                args.Arguments[i]));

        args.Proceed();

        _log.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} return value: {1}", methodName, 
            args.ReturnValue));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I read the book and understand the concept. I am just trying to justify it to someone. I have been told that you can do it manually yourself - which I am sure I can - but my opinion is that postsharp etc. improves productivity. I guess MethodInterceptionAspect is something postsharp offers out of the box if I understand correctly.

Comment: You can't really do AOP manually.  You need a framework to weave the 'Aspects' into the code.  I suppose you could separate out your Cross Cutting Concerns into static utility classes and do it that way, but you'd lose a lot.  It's kinda like the DIY DI vs a DI Framework.  You could do Dependency Injection yourself, but it's so much nicer with a framework.

Comment: The idea is that if you have 1000 business methods or whatever, and they need to log, you apply the logging aspect/advice to your business methods.. if this requirement changes, e.g. how logging is done, what arguments to include etc. you only have a single aspect to update. if you do it manually using "glue-code" you will have to update 1000 call sites..
And logging is maybe the most naive use case for AOP, the real Power comes when you apply undo/redo to objects, or Dirty tracking to entities etc.